How to use argument as a value inside snowflake SQL function?
I'm trying to create a SQL function like below, I was passing databasename, schemaname and table name as input. I was not able to use the input database name for the information_schema
below is my Snowflake function:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FN_GET_COLUMNS(DatabaseName VARCHAR,SchemaName VARCHAR,TableName VARCHAR)
RETURNS VARCHAR
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
$$


WITH data_columns AS (
    SELECT UPPER(column_name) AS column_name
    FROM information_schema.columns 
    WHERE table_catalog = UPPER(DatabaseName)
        AND table_schema = UPPER(SchemaName)
        AND table_name = UPPER(TableName)
        AND is_identity != 'YES'
) SELECT LISTAGG('src.'||column_name, ', ') within group(order by column_name) as data_col
FROM data_columns
WHERE NOT STARTSWITH(column_name,'__')
$$; 

I was not able to use DatabaseName.information_schema.columns [Where DatabaseName is the input argument]?
Any solution for this?

You probably need to construct your FQN from your input parameters and then wrap it in the IDENTIFER keyword: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/identifier-literal

Thanks Nick! for response. Seems like there is limitation in using the identifier inside Function. Instead of using the Function, I have used the Stored procedure.
with a function we  can't use dynamic sql where we can use DatabaseName.information_schema.columns. It can only be information_schema.columns in the database we specify in the function non dynamically or it'll only be the database that we create the function in.

you should be referencing the parameters with ":" before it.
--untested
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FN_GET_COLUMNS(DatabaseName VARCHAR,SchemaName VARCHAR,TableName VARCHAR)
RETURNS VARCHAR
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
$$


WITH data_columns AS (
    SELECT UPPER(column_name) AS column_name
    FROM information_schema.columns 
    WHERE table_catalog = UPPER(:DatabaseName)
        AND table_schema = UPPER(:SchemaName)
        AND table_name = UPPER(:TableName)
        AND is_identity != 'YES'
) SELECT LISTAGG('src.'||column_name, ', ') within group(order by column_name) as data_col
FROM data_columns
WHERE NOT STARTSWITH(column_name,'__')
$$;


Hi Himanshu, Function works, but it is confined to the scope of the database in which Function was created.
I guess my question was not bit clear, I want to use the databasename input argument before the schema "information_schema"
(ex: :databasename.inoformation_schema.columns) where databasename should be inout argument of function

Hi Tharun, please try using Identifier as suggested by NickW above,  some thing like this v_db_name := :DatabaseName|| '.Schame_name.table_name';
select count(*) into :v_sis_load_chk from  identifier(:v_db_name);
